# Node.js using async.forEach with async operation

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

have a function, that needs to loop over an array, perform an async operation on each item, then finally callback to the caller.

I can get the basic case for async.forEach to work. 
When I do this, it works

```
async.forEach(documentDefinitions(), function (documentDefinition, callback) {               
    createdList.push(documentDefinition);
    callback(); //tell the async iterator we're done

}, function (err) {
    console.log('iterating done ' + createdList.length);
    callback(createdList); //tell the calling method we're done, and return the created docs.
});
```

The length of createdList is the correct length.

Now, I want to execute another async operation each time through the loop. So I try changing the code to the following;

```
function insert(link, callback){
    var createList = [];

    async.each(
       documentDefinitions(), 

       function iterator(item, callback) {
           create(collectionLink, item, function (err, created) {
               console.log('created');
               createdList.push(created);
               callback();
           });
       },

       function (err) {
          console.log('iterating done ' + createdList.length);
          callback(createdList);
       }
    );
}
```

where create() is my new async operation.
now I get an endless loop and we never seem to hit callback(createdList);

I event tried moving the callback() inside the callback of the async create() method, but neither of these work.

please help me, i'm stuck in callback hell!

Comment: Moving the call to `callback()` inside the `create` callback is the way to do this. Not sure why that wouldn't work for you.

Comment: not sure either. wondering if it is because callback is defined twice. once in the loop, and again at the containing function. wonder if it is getting confused.

Comment: btw. what is the difference between async.forEach and async.each ?

Comment: No difference; `forEach` is just an alias of `each`.  Can you update your question to show what you're trying with the `callback()` call inside the `create` callback?

Comment: updated to show full function

Comment: Where is the code for `create`?

Comment: create() is a function from a database driver that does an async operation against a database. i.e. it isn't my code

Comment: This would be quite easily handle with promises. You can look at Bluebird which is a great promise library. https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird

Comment: I will definitely look in to promises at some stage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the func to the following fixed it.

```
function insert(link, callback){
    var createdList = [];
    async.each(
        documentDefinitions(), 

        function iterator(item, cb) {
            create(collectionLink, item, function (err, created) {
                console.log('created');
                createdList.push(created);
                cb();
            });
        },

        function (err) {
            console.log('iterating done ' + createdList.length);
            callback(createdList);
        }
    );
}
```

Not sure, but I think it was changing the one occurrence of callback to cb that did the trick.

Was it a scoping problem and they were getting confuse?